# file_field not saving path in google chrome

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a file field element in a view to save path of the file as follows:

```
<%= file_field (:def, :sset) %>
```

Later I am accessing this file path as params[:def][:sset]. It works fine in Internet Explorer
but Google Chrome is only saving the filename not file path. Is there any alternative to save file path too in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. I had to put `:multipart=>true` in the `form_tag`.